# Replace default "new" action to custom created command SPFX

Tags: development, sharepoint-framework

I've created a new extension to SPFx to create a new item for a list. This contains more checks then the default action, because some fields depends on an other field. My question is now how could I replace the default "new" command by my custom created "new" command?

[image]

Same thing with the "edit" command.

Comment: You need hide original with CSS and move your to its position.

Comment: @ZdeněkVinduška: Removing the buttons using CSS is not a good opinion because other buttons from other lists will being removed to. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately removing default buttons in not supported in modern SharePoint right now. One alternative is to customize the form in power-apps and remove all the fields from the form. Leaving the form with a label "This form isn't functional".

Now the user is supposed to click the other command button. This is what we did as a work around.

Comment: Can I [connect a SPFx webpart and a SP list using dynamic data](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257031/connect-spfx-webpart-and-sp-list-using-dynamic-data)? If that is possible, it would be a great thing...

Comment: Can I do the same thing with giving nobody the create and edit rights?

Answer (score 3):

You can always, although it is not recommend, hide buttons with css, with the help of a **spfx application customizer.**

Lets say you want to hide the "new button", just need to make yout **spfx extension** import a custom `css` or `sass` file with:

```css
  button[data-automationid="newCommand"] {
    display: none;
  }
```